Docker Compose thinks file is directory - Code 0
I'm trying to install traefik on my server using docker compose. I have this code in .yaml file
---
# -- (Optional) When using a custom network
 networks:
   frontend:
     external: true
 services:
  traefik:
    image: docker.io/library/traefik:v3.0.3
    container_name: traefik
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      # -- (Optional) Enable Dashboard, don't do in production
      # - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/traefik
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    # -- (Optional) When using Cloudflare as Cert Resolver
    environment:
       - CF_DNS_API_TOKEN=SIstTuieaC0fhnatt4zcJ3ix7zKfMv3I0Ky1jpHo
    # -- (Optional) When using a custom network
    networks:
       - frontend
    restart: unless-stopped

But, everytime I'm trying to run it, docker start, container showes up in portainer GUI, but terminal end with code 0, and this error message
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container traefik  Recreated                                                                                    0.0s
Attaching to traefik
traefik  | {"level":"error","error":"command traefik error: read /etc/traefik/traefik.yaml: is a directory","time":"2024-07-02T19:05:23Z","message":"Command error"}
traefik exited with code 0

I have config file in same same cataloge where docker-compose.yaml file is, but i /config folder
I tried changing directories in file, but nothing worked

Does this help? https://community.traefik.io/t/unable-to-go-past-the-traefik-yml-is-a-directory-error/19345

What sort of file is ./config/traefik.yaml on your host system?  Since Docker will automatically create both host and container directories, it's possible the file never existed but a previous iteration of this Compose setup caused an empty directory to be created.

@DavidMaze This is entire content of my traefik .yaml file
https://pastebin.com/N8QiSRgY
